# Whenever I use 'manage.py' I get the following error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Whenever I try to run development server or migrate, I get this error...please can someone help. Thanks

I am using postgres and I've set up everything very well, I cloned the project and hen when I try to migrate, I get this error...

Here is the trackback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/bloverse-web/bloverse/settings.py", line 31, in <module>
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', default=[], cast=Csv())
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 85, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 79, in get
    return cast(value)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 233, in __call__
    return self.post_process(transform(s) for s in splitter)
  File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 233, in <genexpr>
    return self.post_process(transform(s) for s in splitter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 295, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 136, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Settings.py
Here is what the atabase in settings, looks like...

```
# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }

# # always make sure "psycopg2" is installed

try:
    # production database on Heroku
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(
            default=config('DATABASE_URL')
        )
    }
except:
    # local database for development

    DATABASES = {  
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),                      
            'USER': config('DB_USER'),                      
            'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASS'),     # remove "password" & add yours
            'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),                      
            'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),                      
        }
    }
```

manage.py
Here is how my manage.py looks like...

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bloverse.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Post some code that reproduce this.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to post the code here...But is it not possible to know what the issue is from the trackback?

Comment: No. Not with just a traceback that is only django with no information about how it's set up.

Comment: I have edited it...to have some code...maybe that could help

Comment: What is decouple.py ? (File "/home/uzzy/Documents/Bloverse/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py")

Comment: I finally saw the problem in decouple.py...uninstalled and installed the version in requirements.txt
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted decouple.py...uninstalled python-decouple, and then reinstalled python-decouple==3.1, the error was gone.